# Declaration ImageView on recylclerView (Cannot resolve method)

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

i would like to delcare an imageview in a recycler view, but i have a issue with the method "FindViewById" at the line "green = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.statecolorG);"

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Requete> items;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private int itemLayout;
    private ImageView green;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Requete> items, int itemLayout) {
        this.items = items;
        this.itemLayout = itemLayout;
    }
public void update(List<Requete> nimp)
{
    items.clear();
    items.addAll(nimp);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Requete item = items.get(position);
        ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder)holder;
        vh.primaryText.setText(Integer.toString(item.getState()));
        vh.primaryText.setText(item.getserviceName());
        vh.data = item;
        green = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.statecolorG);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends SwipeToAction.ViewHolder<Requete>{
        public TextView primaryText;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            primaryText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleItem);
        }

    }
```

Maybe the placement is wrong ?

Comment: What's you issue exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)You should never be calling findViewById in onBindViewHolder.  The purpose of a viewHolder is to hold all those views.  Its should be done in the constructor of your ViewHolder.

2)An adapter doesn't have a findViewById function as it isn't a viewgroup.  You probably want to call that on itemView in the ViewHolder constructor.

Comment: Thanks Gabe, so it's mean i should calling it in the "OnCreateViewHolder" ? just few lines above ?

Comment: It should be in the actual constructor of the ViewHolder class.  Which is itself called in onCreateViewHolder.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your image view in view holder class

```
    public static class ViewHolder extends SwipeToAction.ViewHolder<Requete>{
        public TextView primaryText;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            primaryText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleItem);
            green = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.statecolorG);

       }
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call findViewById because it's not a function on the RecyclerView Adapter, also you should not declare ImageView inside of the Adapter. It should be declared inside of your ViewHolder and then call findViewById() on itemView, like you do with the TextView and assign the reference to the 'green' ImageView variable. NOTE: An ImageView with the id 'statecolorG' must be declared in the same layout file 'item_view.xml' that you are inflating inside of onCreateViewHolder.